# Mapping Payload issue

Tags: rest, request

My Payload

```
{
    "id": 2135,
    "name": "Krups test 43 ",
    "customerName": "jeweller2,Kays",
    "briefGivenById": 222,
    "briefGivenByNameDraft": "Merchandiser",
    "userId": null,
    "briefGivenByType": 2,
    "metalQualityId": null,
    "diamondWtFrom": 0.1,
    "diamondWtTo": 1,
    "retailPriceFrom": 100,
    "retailPriceTo": 500,
    "partyMasterId": null,
    "routeId": 24,
    "sampleFinalSelection": 10,
    "completionDate": "2023-10-17",
    "priority": "High",
    "draftId": null,
    "refBriefId": null,
    "refBriefName": null,
    "factoryPriceFrom": 99,
    "factoryPriceTo": 495,
    "margin": "1",
    "isGroup": "1",
    "isValid": 0
}
```

My Dto

```
package com.kps.dto;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.kps.utils.MyJsonDateDeserializer;
import com.kps.utils.MyJsonDateSerializer;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Builder
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class BriefDTO extends AuditableDTO{

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String nameShortcode;   
    private String customerName;
    
    @JsonSerialize(using = MyJsonDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = MyJsonDateDeserializer.class)
    private Date completionDate;
    private String summary;
    private String createdByName;
    private String status;
    private String priority;
    private Integer userId;
    private Integer routeId;
    private Integer metalId;
    private Double diamondWtFrom;
    private Double diamondWtTo;
    private Integer retailPriceFrom;
    private Integer retailPriceTo;
    private Integer sampleFinalSelection;
    private Integer metalQualityId;
    private List<BriefPropertiesDTO>  briefPropertyDTOList;
    private List<SubBriefDTO>  subBriefDTOList;
    
    
    private String metalName ;
    private String metalQualityName;
    
    private Integer partyMasterId;
    
    private String briefGivenByName;
    private String partyMasterName;
    private String briefGivenByTypeName;
    
    private Object briefGivenById;
    private Integer briefGivenByType;
    
    private List<BriefDateDTO> deadLineDatesDTO;
    
    private Integer refBriefId;
    private Integer marketZoneId;
    private String marketZoneName;
    private String refBriefName;
    
    private String routeName;
    private String curencyCode;
    private Integer draftId;
    private Integer factoryPriceFrom;
    private Integer factoryPriceTo;
    private Double margin;
    private Integer isGroup;
    private Integer refBriefGroupId;
    private String refBriefGroupName;
    private Integer isStory;
    private Integer isValid;
    private Boolean isUndo;
    private Integer currUserId;
    private Long listOfStory;
    private Integer listOfSubBrief;
    private String briefCreatedBy;
    private Integer isBriefGroup;
    private String briefSubBriefCount;
    private Double pricing;
    private Boolean editAfterStoryApproval;

    public BriefDTO(Integer id, String name, String nameShortcode, String customerName, Date completionDate,
            String summary, String createdByName, String status, String priority, Integer userId, Integer routeId,
            Integer metalId, Double diamondWtFrom, Double diamondWtTo, Integer retailPriceFrom, Integer retailPriceTo,
            Integer sampleFinalSelection, Integer metalQualityId, List<BriefPropertiesDTO> briefPropertyDTOList,
            List<SubBriefDTO> subBriefDTOList, String metalName, String metalQualityName, Integer partyMasterId,
            String briefGivenByName, String partyMasterName, String briefGivenByTypeName, Integer briefGivenById,
            Integer briefGivenByType, List<BriefDateDTO> deadLineDatesDTO) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.nameShortcode = nameShortcode;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.completionDate = completionDate;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.createdByName = createdByName;
        this.status = status;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.routeId = routeId;
        this.metalId = metalId;
        this.diamondWtFrom = diamondWtFrom;
        this.diamondWtTo = diamondWtTo;
        this.retailPriceFrom = retailPriceFrom;
        this.retailPriceTo = retailPriceTo;
        this.sampleFinalSelection = sampleFinalSelection;
        this.metalQualityId = metalQualityId;
        this.briefPropertyDTOList = briefPropertyDTOList;
        this.subBriefDTOList = subBriefDTOList;
        this.metalName = metalName;
        this.metalQualityName = metalQualityName;
        this.partyMasterId = partyMasterId;
        this.briefGivenByName = briefGivenByName;
        this.partyMasterName = partyMasterName;
        this.briefGivenByTypeName = briefGivenByTypeName;
        this.briefGivenById = briefGivenById;
        this.briefGivenByType = briefGivenByType;
        this.deadLineDatesDTO = deadLineDatesDTO;
    } 
    
    
}
```

My controller

```
public ResponseEntity<?> createBriefHandler(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @RequestBody BriefDTO briefDTO)
```

I'm currently printing `briefDTO.getIsGroup()` and `briefDTO.getMargin()`. Sometimes, I'm able to retrieve the assigned values, but quite often, I'm getting null values. This issue occurs when I include an ID in my payload. Strangely, it seems that even when I omit the ID, it's not consistently working either. I've created my own getter and setter methods, but the problem persists. I've also double-checked the naming conventions, and everything appears to be correct.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which language/framework/library you are working with. Your title is not clear enough as to the problem you are experiencing. You haven't been clear about what your question is. You need to put some wrapping around your code snippets with the 'language' name e.g. json, javascript or similar. I suggest you put the problem you're having in the title along with the language you are using, use your last sentence in a separate paragraph with the specific thing you want help with and use more tags to represent your programming language and libraries etc. you are using e.g. 'Rea